# Posting error with P2 theme

Tags: theme-p2

I'm getting the error:
"Whoops! Looks like you are not connected to the server. P2 could not connect with WordPress."

when trying to reply to comments/posts on P2, I'm on v1.5.2

Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with permalinks and Ajax. If so, the solution is simply to refresh your permalinks, by visiting `Settings -> Permalinks` in your admin, and clicking "Save".

Comment: That didn't fix it Chip, anything else I can try?

Comment: Other quick research seems to indicate that this is a long-standing, recurring bug/issue with the P2 Theme itself. Your best bet is to post to the P2 support forums.

Comment: It works if I set permalinks back to default with the post ids, then when I set back to nice permalinks it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I just reset the Permalinks to default.  And then reset them to the 'Post Name' configuration.  It seemed to work.

Comment: FYI: You just "flushed" your rewrite rules...